# Extracting meta data from nupkg file with F# looks like C# Linq

Tags: f#

The code snippet below examines a nuget package file (zip file with meta) and extracts all file names referenced inside. The final result should be a `Set<string>` with all file names. My problem is that the code looks like a nested Linq query in c# and the usage of `Seq.iter` blocks me to build the `Set` collection. Can you please give me some kind of advice how to improve the F# code? Am I missing some fundamental concept?

```
getDependencies nugetPackagesFile
                |> Seq.iter(fun (name,ver) ->
                    name + "." + ver
                    |> fun pkgName ->
                        !! ("./src/packages/*/" + pkgName + ".nupkg")
                        |> Seq.iter(fun pkg ->
                            global.NuGet.ZipPackage(pkg).GetFiles()
                            |> Seq.iter(fun file -> filename file.Path |> printfn "%s")))
```

Current output:

```
Elders.Cronus.dll
Elders.Cronus.pdb
Elders.Cronus.DomainModeling.dll
Elders.Cronus.DomainModeling.pdb
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
log4net.dll
log4net.xml
Elders.Multithreading.Scheduler.dll
Elders.Multithreading.Scheduler.pdb
protobuf-net.dll
protobuf-net.pdb
protobuf-net.xml
protobuf-net.dll
protobuf-net.pdb
protobuf-net.xml
protobuf-net.dll
protobuf-net.pdb
protobuf-net.xml
```

Comment: Please only state the code purpose in the title

Comment: all f# looks like linq to me!

Comment: is ot the GetFiles call which is making this non-functional? maybe if you build the list of files first?

Comment: @Ewan the call Seq.iter is what bothers me because it returns unit. I am missing something like Select in Linq

Comment: IEnumerable.Select is Seq.map in F#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to actually test (I can only guess what `getDependencies`, `nugetPackagesFile`, `!!` and `filename` are), something along the following should produce your desired `set` of dependencies:

```
getDependencies nugetPackagesFile
|> Seq.collect (fun (name, ver) -> 
       !! (sprintf "./src/packages/*/%s.%s.nupkg" name ver)
       |> Seq.collect (fun pkg -> NuGet.ZipPackage(pkg).GetFiles())
       |> Seq.map (fun f -> filename f.Path))
|> Set.ofSeq
```

or, depending on your taste (kind of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) vs. [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search))

```
getDependencies nugetPackagesFile
|> Seq.collect (fun (name, ver) -> !! (sprintf "./src/packages/*/%s.%s.nupkg" name ver))
|> Seq.collect (fun pkg -> NuGet.ZipPackage(pkg).GetFiles())
|> Seq.map (fun f -> filename f.Path)
|> Set.ofSeq
```

where `Seq.collect` and `map` correspond to `IEnumerable.SelectMany` respectively `Select` in C#

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very much imperative. I think this reads better:

```
for name, ver in getDependencies nugetPackagesFile do
    let pkgName = name + "." + ver
    for pkg in !! ("./src/packages/*/" + pkgName + ".nupkg") do
        for file in global.NuGet.ZipPackage(pkg).GetFiles() do
            filename file.Path |> printfn "%s"
```